# Grab Data From Three Tables and Where Date Range Equals

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an SQL script so that I grab certain columns from each table and only grab them by a date range from and to. I have tried but the date range just doesn't seem to work.

For example, I want to **select** the date range **from** 2020-09-29 00:01:00 **to** 2020-09-29 23:59:00 so the SQL only grabs orders from the date range.

These are my tables and the data I want from the SQL:

[image: SQL Query and database]

So I wish to grab the date range and pick out what supplier the customer ordered from on that date.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What is the query you're trying and what isn't working about it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue I had with date range.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.OrderDate , Supplier.SupplierName FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Item_Details ON Orders.OrderID=Item_Details.OrderID
INNER JOIN Supplier ON Item_Details.SupplierID=Supplier.SupplierID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '2020-09-29 00:01:00' and '2020-09-29 23:59:00';
```

Now working correctly